# Get the values from 2nd and 3rd table for the matched values in 1st table

Tags: php, mysql

I am a jQuery developer and I do not have good idea on how to retrieve data from tables. I am just trying to learn it.

I have a special case to deal with. Consider three tables

```
tb1 
-----------------------------------------------
    pid    fname     lname       cid       eid
    12      jo         mo        16345     2345
    13      ko         ro        16324     2435

tb2
-----------------------------------------------
    cid     cname
   16345    amazed
   16324    bored

tb3
------------------------------------------------
    eid      ename
    2345      nolo
    21345     johny
```

I want to retrieve the data for the matching pid value. Say,

```
select * from tb1 where pid = 12
```

It returns me `pid, fname, lname, cid, eid`

The `cid` value is 16345, Instead the number. I want that `cid` value to be matched to the `tb2` and get the cname column value that is `amazed` and same with the `eid` that is the `ename : nolo` I want those numbers to be matched to tb2 and tb3 and get their string values.

I could do it using 3 MySQL queries

**This is what I have tried**

```
 $result = mysql_query("select * from tb1 where pid = 12");
 $row = mysql_fetch_array($result,MYSQL_ASSOC);
 $cname = mysql_query("select cname from tb2 where cid = '$row[cid]'");
 $x =  mysql_fetch_array($cname,MYSQL_ASSOC);
 $cname = mysql_query("select ename from tb3 where eid = '$row[eid]'"); 
 $y =  mysql_fetch_array($cname,MYSQL_ASSOC);
```

But I feel the code is not ideal. I guess there must be a way to retrieve in a single query but I am not sure what it must be. Maybe joins or sub-queries.

Comment: you can use `JOIN` queries here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use joins on 3 tables

```
SELECT tb1.*, tb2.cname, tb3.ename from tb1
JOIN tb2 ON tb1.cid = tb2.cid
JOIN tb3 ON tb1.eid = tb3.eid
WHERE tb1.pid = 12
```

Hope this helps

Comment: well I would try and let you know if it works but I  have a question it must be tb1.*, tb2.cname right?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
 SELECT *.t1, t2.cname, t3.ename from tb1 as t1
    JOIN tb2 as t2 ON t1.cid = t2.cid
    JOIN tb3 as t3 ON t1.eid = t3.eid 
    WHERE t1.pid = 12
```